# How to exclude path from dd command?

Tags: 14.04, dd

How should I use dd command so that I can exclude path from dd command.

Comment: AFAIK `dd` can't  do this. Use `rsync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you can remove the directory from the partition `dd` is not the command you need. `dd` does its job based on sectors so no, you can't exclude directories from `dd`.

The command you need is `tar`. That has a `--exclude=` option and can compress at the same time. And `rsync` is also a possibility.

Comment: Now it makes sense. Cheers!